# Parse REST API: Having the channel name, can I get the device type before actually sending to Push?

Tags: php, rest, parsing, push

We have a server which occasionally sends pushes to our users. Every user has his own channel name in Parse. Because our ios and android pushes look entirely different, we try to send the push two times, one time targetting his channel name and android devices and one time targetting his channel name and ios devices:

```
$aAndroidPush = array(
    "where" => array(
        "deviceType" => "Android",
        "channels" => array('$in' => array("push_user"))
    ),
    "data" => array(
        "action" => "com.android.action",
        "alertMessage" => "this is a push",
        "t" => "web",
        "m" => 0
    )
);

$aIOSPush = array(
    "where" => array(
        "deviceType" => "ios",
        "channels" => array('$in' => array("push_user"))
    ),
    "data" => array(
        "alert" => "this is a push",
        "sound" => "p.mp3",
        "t" => "web",
        "m" => 0 ,
        "badge" => ""
    )
);

$aHeaders = array(  
       "Content-Type: application/json",  
       "X-Parse-Application-Id: parse_app_id" .,  
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: parse_rest_key" .   
);

$oRest = curl_init();
curl_setopt($oRest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$aHeaders);  
curl_setopt($oRest,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($oRest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
curl_setopt($oRest,CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.parse.com/1/push");   
curl_setopt($oRest, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  

curl_setopt($oRest, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($aIOSPush));
curl_exec($oRest);

curl_setopt($oRest, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($aAndroidPush));
curl_exec($oRest);
```

So my question is, is there a way to make a query in parse (REST API or the new PHP API) before sending the pushes, to see if the targetting channel is using either android or ios and thus sending only one push request and not two?

Comment: According to [this](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#options-platform/REST) the REST API targets both by default.  Have you tried removing the device type and standardizing the push array?  E.g. use the intersection of the push array.

Comment: As I mentioned, it is not possible because the push looks entirely different. For example, If I use the alert keyword for android as well, than the default ParseBroadcastReceiver will get triggered instead of my custom one, so I have to use alertMessage. I can not use alertMessage for iOS because iOS only listens for alert.

Comment: @PetrosMastrantonas - If you've solved the problem and one of the answers to your question helped, please mark that answer as accepted to help future visitors to SO see how to solve this same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Adam Link while your answer was the most helpful one (thats why you got the reward) I chose not to solve it that way. I integrated an ios/android field in our database and do it that way. That way I don't need to make another parse request.

Answer (score 4):

Parse has great [PHP docs](https://parse.com/docs/php_guide) that can help here. Because you are using a custom push notification handler in Android, the default Push code won't likely work for you.

One of the things to look at is the Parse Query to the "_Installation" object.

Your code would be:

```
$query = new ParseQuery("_Installation"); // or try ParseInstallation()?
$query->equalTo("objectId", $yourObjectId);
$result = $query->first();
if ($result->get("deviceType") == "android") {
   // we are Android
 } else {
   // we are iOS
 }
```

It would help to know what other data you have on the Installation prior to the push. If you have `objectId`, that makes this code work. If you have an array of `channels`, you'll need to select users in those channels, and then `foreach` over the array, grab the `objectId`, and make a query that way.

Happy to explain if you leave a comment letting me know one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Parse and I am not sure what kind of information you have stored related to the user. But seems like if you have the installation objectId then you can use it to retrive the deviceType of the user.

For more details [Reference](https://parse.com/docs/rest#installations-retrieving)

**Edited:**

Seems like there is yet another way of doing it.

You can [Query Installations](https://parse.com/docs/rest#installations-querying) and pass [Query Constraints](https://parse.com/docs/rest#queries-constraints)to get the desired user object in return.

Answer (score 0):

From the initial request you can detect device type from request using [MobileESP](http://blog.mobileesp.com/) library.

Comment: How does this library connect with the Parse Database?

Answer (score 0):

Try not to send your notifications twice. You can remove deviceType from the channel.

Parse should take care of sending the notifications to the registered device, irrespective of the device type, i.e., iPhone or Android.

But if you absolutely have to send notification to only one type of devices here is how: https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#options-platform/PHP

Comment: As I mentioned, it is not possible to remove deviceType because the push looks entirely different. For example, If I use the alert keyword for android as well, than the default ParseBroadcastReceiver will get triggered instead of my custom one, so I have to use alertMessage. I can not use alertMessage for iOS because iOS only listens for alert.

I already send notifications to Android and iOS but I would like to know it before I send a msg, which device I am targeting. Your advice is same as the REST API, just with PHP Code.